# how to fix mysql installation if I accidentally delete some file of mysql package

Tags: apt, mysql

I accidentally delete  /etc/mysql (and other files), Now every time I try to install a new package, apt will fail.

Then I try to fix it with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

but it will fail with below error messages. my understanding is: apt try to stop mysql before it do any operation, but because files are missing, so it can't stop correctly. How to fix this?

```
Preconfiguring packages ... (Reading database ... 261168 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5 There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it. Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you manually stop the service with `sudo systemctl stop mysql`?

Comment: no, I delete the file of servic. not sure how ubuntu determine it need to stop it.

Comment: It needs to stop the service because otherwise there is a risk of corrupting the database. However, if you are sure there are no other database operations running, at this point you might as well just `kill` the process.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to another stupid mistake, the first one it to manually delete mysql configuration files. the second one is I didn't delete them all, there are 2 remaining soft link in

> /etc/systemd/system

which point to mysql service which is deleted by me. I guess apt try to make sure mysql service is inactive, when apt find mysql service file in

> /etc/systemd/system

apt will run it. But because they are pointed to invalid files so the operation will fail. after I delete them , apt work again. 
I think systemctl disable may also work, but I didn't try it.